# How can I cut and paste one part of a photo on top of another in iOS?

Tags: ios, graphics, image-editing

I have two versions of the same image.  One has some text on it (three lines of text), and the other is the original with no text.

I want to remove the bottom line of text.  To do this, I cut and paste the part of the original (the part without the line of text) over the bottom line of text in the image with the text.

In Photoshop on the Mac, this is easy:

1. Open both images.
2. Select the bottom of the original image (where there is no text) and copy.
3. Paste this over the image with text to cover up the bottom line.
4. Export.

How can I do this on iOS?  I tried using Photoshop Fix, but all I see is "crop," no cut and paste.  I'm not committed to Photoshop as a solution; any way to use part of one image to cover another will do.

Comment: Wait.. but you already have the image without text. Why the stitching then?

Comment: @KevinGrabher Because I want to remove the bottom line only, and leave the two lines above it. (All three lines are added together by an app that does not provide a setting to remove the bottom line.)

Comment: There are tons of basic online image editors that can do this. At least one will work on an iOS browser.